# Отключение слайдера owlCarousel при смене разрешения

Tags: javascript, jquery, адаптивная-верстка, slider

Есть список товаров в виде карточек, который выглядит как обычная галерея (в ряду по 3 карточки и есть несколько таких рядов). Сайт адаптивный, нужно при маленькой ширине экрана этот список товаров превращать в слайдер.

Проблема в том, что при расширении экрана необходимо, чтобы этот список снова превращался в галерею, но этого не происходит, он продолжает отображаться как слайдер.

Ниже пример моей реализации, тут я думал просто удалять метод, но это не работает:

```
            var catalogSlider = $( '.catalog-galary' );
            function setSlider (){
                if ( $(window).width() < 480 ){
                    catalogSlider.owlCarousel( {
                        items: 1,
                        itemsDesktop:  false,
                        itemsDesktopSmall: false,
                        itemsTablet: false,
                        itemsMobile: [480, 1],
                        navigation : true,
                        pagination : true,
                        slideSpeed : 400,
                        navigationText : false
                    } )
                } else {
                    delete catalogSlider.owlCarousel;
                }
            }

            setSlider();
            $( window ).resize( setSlider );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо использовать метод `.destroy()` для удаления функционала слайдера с контента, на котором этот слайдер был инициализирован:

> destroy() method unwrap whole plugin and leave original pre carousel
>   structure
>
> Syntax:  `owldata.destroy();`
>
> ```
>   $('.destroy').click(function(e){
>     e.preventDefault()
>     $("#owl-demo").data('owlCarousel').destroy();
>   });
> ```

Источник: [owlCarousel: content manipulations](http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/manipulations.html)

Comment: огромное спасибо, вы мой спаситель!